# Can we use large payload support in SQS send message batch in Mule 4

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, mulesoft, mule4

Can we use large payload support in SQS send message batch in a Mule 4 application? When I used the large payload support by giving s3 bucket details, I am still getting the BatchRequestTooLongException. The same configuration works in SQS send message but not working on send batch message. Any sample or example related to this will be helpful as I did not find any examples on how to implement this.

Comment: What is the size of what you are trying to send? Version of Mule and SQS connector?

Comment: Payload size is sometimes more than 300kb as the sqs expects it to be under 256kb. We are using Mule 4.3.0 and Amazon SQS v5.11.0

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from SQS. I believe it is a limitation on the SQS batch action. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-batch-api-actions.html) says there is a 256 KB size limit per batch:

> The total size of all messages that you send in a single SendMessageBatch call can't exceed 262,144 bytes (256 KB).

Comment: For SQS:send-message, we have an option to add sqs:large-payload-support using s3 bucket for messages size more than 256kb but the same option is not working for sqs:send-message-batch.

Comment: I'm not sure if SQS supports that scenario for send batch.